# Botium-cli quickstart process it taking so long and long

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface

I am installing botium in my Windows 10 machine through quickstart method. When i run  the command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up
```

It takes so long and long time. I waited for hours to finish the process but it did not complete.

I am following this [blog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botium-box) to setup botium

[Here is cli snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz20W.png)

Comment: Are you sure the container isn't up and running? What output are you expecting? Try `docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up -d` (`-d` puts it in the background) and check whether you can reach whatever service you want to reach. Also, please add your `docker-compose-all.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. Botium Box is online, just connect to http://127.0.0.1:4000 with your browser. If you want to run Botium Box server in the background, just add the *-d* command line switch to docker-compose:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up -d
```

You can then see the log output with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml logs -f
```